# type expected on a point in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

for this line:

```
Private _allowedLocations As Point() = New () {New Point(50, 50), New Point(500, 500), New Point(700, 100)
```

i am getting the error "type expected for 'new ()'

whats wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to repeat the type name before the ().  You can rewrite the code as follows

```
Private _allowedLocations As Point() = New Point() {New Point(50, 50), New Point(500, 500), New Point(700, 100) }
```

Answer (score 3):

I thought the whole New-expression was unnecessary:

```
Private _allowedLocations As Point() = {New Point(50, 50), New Point(500, 500), New Point(700, 100) }
```

Comment: Yes it is.  It was actually me providing the offending code to start with; auto-converted from C# but still. I am ashamed...

Comment: it was not offensive at all, i want to thank you again for helping me

Comment: When VB10 arrives with implicitly typed arrays, you could leave off the "As Point" too.

Comment: Fredrik -- good to see you. Well, you gave me an opportunity to flash my wicked VB.NET skills :)